# not able to see the preview for cropper js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

I have created an application using **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** for cropping an images, the application is working and the image is cropping but I am not able to see the preview, my preview div is not populating anything correctly while cropping. My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f7VvWp05B6B9RclfjLv7?p=preview)**

**script**

```
 var $image = $('.img-container > img'),
    $dataRotate = $('#dataRotate'),
    options = {
       modal: true,
       guides: true,
       autoCrop: false,
       dragCrop: true,
       movable: true,
       resizable: true,
       zoomable: false,
       touchDragZoom: false,
       mouseWheelZoom: false,
       preview: '.preview',
      crop: function (data) {
        $dataRotate.val(Math.round(data.rotate));
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the size of the `.preview` element with css. Also set the overflow to hidden, e.g.

```
.preview {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px;
}
```

Also forked [your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/r9ClVEROfpycEkizSIWZ?p=preview) and [your updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XgzpFwgT6oBcSE0rpaS9?p=preview).

Comment: can we give fixed height and width for preview, since I am using free mode

Comment: You meen free aspect ratio? Yes that seems to work. You just have to have some fixed height/width wrapper for it too if you don't want the rest of the page moving when cropping a squashed area.

Comment: yes free aspect ratio...how to make the height and width fixed

Comment: no its seems giveing wrong cropped image, see this, http://i.stack.imgur.com/Womni.png,just i increased the width and height also added border [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dQkBwvH9xCEvkmv9VSJ9?p=preview)

Comment: I had a mistake in my plunk for a couple minutes where there was min-height instead of height, try reloading it. See my answer for the fixed version of your plunk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75898/discussion-between-alex-man-and-ekuusela).

Comment: do you have any idea on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814895/converting-canvas-to-blob-using-cropper-js