# converting canvas to blob using cropper js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I have created an application using **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** for cropping an images. The application is working and the image is cropping, after that I am trying to send the cropped image as blob to the server side for storing,

As per the **[cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)** documentation we can use **canvas.toDataURL** to get a Data URL, or use **canvas.toBlob** to get a blob and upload it to server with FormData. when I tried **canvas.toDataURL()** I am getting the base64 string, but actually I need to send the file as blob so I tried with **canvas.toBlob()** but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: canvas.toBlob is not a function` in chrome and `TypeError: Not enough arguments to HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob.` in Firefox

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is like this

```
var canvas = $image.cropper("getCroppedCanvas", undefined);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('mainImage', $("#inputImage")[0].files[0]);
formData.append('croppedImage', canvas.toBlob());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method toBlob is asynchronous and require two arguments, the callback function and image type (there is optional third parameter for quality):

> void canvas.toBlob(callback, type, encoderOptions);

**Example**

```
if (typeof canvas.toBlob !== "undefined") {
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      // send the blob to server etc.
      ...
  }, "image/jpeg", 0.75);
}
else if (typeof canvas.msToBlob !== "undefined") {
  var blob = canvas.msToBlob()
  // send blob
}
else {
  // manually convert Data-URI to Blob (if no polyfill)
}
```

Not all browsers supports it (IE needs prefix, msToBlob, and it works differently than the standard) and Chrome needs a **[polyfill](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob)**.

**Update** (**[to OP's edit, now removed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29814895/3)**) The main reason why the cropped image is larger is because the original is JPEG, the new is PNG. You can change this by using toDataURL:

```
var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);  // last=quality
```

before passing it to the manual data-uri to Blob. I would recommend using the polyfill as if the browser supports toBlob() it will be many times faster and use less memory overhead than going by encoding a data-uri.

Comment: what I have to do for chrome and IE

Comment: @AlexMan just include the polyfill I linked to for Chrome. In IE you should be able to use canvas.msToBlob(...). Just note that msToBlob works a little different than the standard so using the polyfill also here is recommended

Comment: @AlexMan added example for MS version (untested)

Comment: @AlexMan just note that you cannot append a Blob to the DOM/form. It has to be represented as string (ie. data-uri). You can store the blob as a global variable and pass that in to the method you use to send the data to the server.

Comment: @AlexMan that would be a different question. I would suggest open a new question for that as the original question here was, if I understand correctly, how to use the toBlob() method.

Answer (score 5):

The proper use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

you have to pass the callback and use the blob object within callback. `toBlob()` does not returns the blob rather it accepts a callback which provides `blob` as parameter.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var newImg = document.createElement("img"),
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  newImg.onload = function() {
    // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };

  newImg.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(newImg);
});
```