# PHP How to save a Canvas Snapshot as a PNG from data to server-side, not in base64

Tags: php

So I've been looking around and could only find a way to save the image to a server if the data you send is in base64. I am sending the data as regualar data so nothing I found worked.

Thanks

This is what I tried to use:

```
 <?php
  $data = 'data:image/png;base64,AAAFBfj42Pj4';

  list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
  list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
  $data = base64_decode($data);

  file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
?>
```

I also tried this:

```
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $data));
```

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814895/converting-canvas-to-blob-using-cropper-js

Comment: I already have all of this, I need a PHP script to save the image server side

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to return a Canvas image to PHP is describe in the following post:

[How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

**1) Draw something**

**2) Convert canvas image to URL format (base64)**

**3) Send it to your server via Ajax**

**3) Save base64 on your server as an image**

Comment: I can't send it as base64, only as regular data

Comment: What do you mean, you can't? Why? Is there a physical barrier?

Comment: I have a simple ajax plugin and it doesn't post as base64
Is there a way to do it as regular data?

Comment: The only other option would be to save it as a PNG client side and do a and do a file upload. Take a look at this library: FileSaver.js