# Canvas toBlob is not recognized as a function in Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm using Cropper to get the blob for a cropped image. I'm using the latest versions of Chrome and IE, but I'm getting 'canvas.toBlob is not a function' in Chrome and 'Object doesn't support property or method 'toBlob' in IE. Seems like I'm following the doc correctly but I might be missing some library or something.
Following the doc [here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v2.0.1/README.md#methods) and this thread from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814895/converting-canvas-to-blob-using-cropper-js)

Interestingly enough I can call

```
var t = $("#imageToCrop").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL();
```

and it works fine to return the data but toBlob doesn't seem to work.

Here is my JS and HTML.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("imageToCrop");
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var t = blob;
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
  <canvas id="imageToCrop" style="border: 1px solid black;" src=""></canvas>
</div>
```

I also tried this below but seeing the same errors

```
var t = $("#imageToCrop").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob();
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently, `toBlob` is [only fully supported in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Browser_compatibility). Internet Explorer has partial support from IE 10, but it is vendor-prefixed to what I assume is `msToBlob`. There is however [at least one polyfill available](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob).

Here are the relevant issues for Chrome and Safari:

- [Chromium 67587 (Chrome)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67587)
- [WebKit 71270 (Safari)](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71270)

For some reason, the WebKit bug is marked as "RESOLVED WONTFIX".

Comment: They don't like the toBlob function being synchronous in the spec.